# how would i get the current size of the variable in java

Tags: java, memory-management

Yes , this question is little bit vague and any serious programmer would laugh about it ! Although java does not tell about the sizes it assigns to the varibles ,i mean it can give more memory or less memory depending on the situation( that way it is abstracted !)i know that stuff! but what i am asking is ,is there any technique that i can know about the runtime variable size ? i want to find the addresses of the variables too ! This question does not want any answers like ,see java docs it does not provide those functionality you have asked , i want some kind of hack to do this kind of stuff!

Comment: As far as I know, primitives have a fixed-size (if that's what you are refering to). For memory/address management you could use C++

Comment: maybe I am not serious because I am not laughing ;-)

Comment: java does not provide fixed sizes :(

Comment: easy dude ! , what i meant was java does not provide fixed size primitives ... some programmers may feel wierd @Christian

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh what do you mean by that? Any source? I think they are size-fixed: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: i don't think those are fixed size .. java will promote or demote size ,i have read in complete reference @Christian

Comment: Just curious, why do you need (or want) to know the size?

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh could you provide a link/source that supports what you are telling?

Comment: they want me to do a symbol table program @andars

Comment: The JVM is open source. Just look at the source code.

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=260 @Christian

Comment: why would i get a downvote ,where as my counterpart question gets 204 ups ! :(

Comment: Because you asked it when the other question already exists.

Answer (score -2):

Well, There is no such direct way to get accurate size consumed by each object in JVM. Although you can you use JCONSOLE or other similar monitoring tool to get footprints of the objects dynamically. Again, this is more towards monitoring and performance tuning.

Thanks, Anil

Comment: Incorrect.  See java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation and various utility libraries build around it such as jamm.

Comment: Well, that's approximate size only.. What I am referring is accurate size.